# Use a Userform for MS Word to Input to Values in Form Fields

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I am trying to automate a repetitive manual task for another department.  They have a word template several pages long.  They have to enter data several times each time they use it.  Many of these are repetitive "fields".  I thought about setting up custom form fields.  But having them go through the navigation and know the field names to update them is not optimal.  I found one solution to create a bookmark for each data input, and create links to that bookmark where it needs to be repeated - better but not optimal.  I was hoping to create a userform where they can enter all the data and have it populate bookmarks, custom fields, to whatever.

I found a video that does this, but when I try the code, it does not update the bookmark.  i created userform with Textbox1, and a CommandButton,  and a bookmark in the document called MWDate.  The code I am trying to get to work is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim MWDate As Range
Set MWDate = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MWDate").Range
MWDate.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
Me.Repaint
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

This is a code example I grabbed and modified from the tutorial video.  I don't know what the "Me." is.  It does not populate the bookmark, which tells me it is not getting to the repaint line.  Nor does it ever get to the hide line.

Anyone have a fix?  Or a better way?  Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: This is not enough information- the problem description is unclear. What we basically need is a way to reproduce the issue, nothing more. Is there an error message? What code is used to display the user form? If you take out the repaint and hide lines do you see something different? Is the bookmark a bookmark, or a form field?

Comment: @Cindy Meister - first of all thanks for your questions.
1.There is no specific code to display the userform.  The only code I have is the command button code pasted above.  I just am running the private sub.  It display the userform.  I type in something, and click the command button.  Do I need specific code to do something else with the userform?
2.  Repaint and hide being removed has no change.
3. Yes, as stated above, it is a bookmark, "_ i created userform...and a bookmark in the document called MWDate_"
4.  I have given you everything I have for this little test.

Comment: I asked because you mention form fields, specifically, in the title. And form fields have names that are also bookmarks. Since form fields are involved, is the document protected as a form when the code runs?

Comment: AH, and the "obvious" question: Is there actually text in the UserForm text box when the code is run?

Comment: `Me.` by the way refers to the UserForm. In "tech-speak" the UserForm is an object and the "code behind" is a class. `Me.` is how to refer to the "parent class" from within its code. But important for you is to know that when you type `Me.` (with the dot) in a UserForm's code module you'll get a list of things appropriate to use (IntelliSense) when working with the UserForm's top-level. Such as a list of its controls and various properties (color, for example).

Comment: I understand the confusion now.  If there is a way to do this with form fields, I am fine with that too.

I do type data into the text box when I run it and before clicking the command button.

Comment: Oh, and I am starting with a blank doc and just the bookmark before I try to take this into the template.  And I was getting the Intellisense options when typing the Me. for both occurrences.

Comment: I'm confused, as well, because the code in the question works for me. If you comment out all the lines inside the Sub and put this first:  `MsgBox "testing"` and then in the next line `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MWDate").Range.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text` do you see anything happen? (Being sure to type something in TextBox1 before clicking the button.)

Comment: @Cindy Meister
OK, I got it working.  It was a stupid mistake on my part.  I had renamed the Command button in the properties and had not done that in the sub.  I appreciate your time, and apologize for wasting it.

Comment: As I was washing the dishes it occurred to me that the control name was probably wrong... :-) A tip from long experience with VBA UserForms: If you rename a button, double-click it (again) to get the Sub rather than trying to rename it. Sometimes VBA gets mixed up and won't recognize the renamed Sub! Good luck with your project. Oh, and yes, it's possible to assign UserForm content to form fields when the document is in protected forms mode. Lots of code examples "out there"...